# scope is not getting the model from an input field in a directive and ng-if div container

Tags: angularjs, input, scope, angularjs-directive

I think I'm missing something basic here.
I have a custom directive that have an input with ng-model on it. When I try to access the the value of the ng-model in the ng-change event the scope has no property of the ng-model. for exaple:

```
<input ng-model="myInput" ng-change="onChange()" />
```

and from the controller:

```
$scope.onChange = function() {
     console.log($scope.myInput);
}
```

and here is a plunkr I made with the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/EnPE7p?p=info

Thanks,
e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

Since there is a ng-if on the div containing the input, the ng-if creates it's own inheriting scope. So in order to have the ng-model get bind in 2 way with the input value, the ng-model need to be assigned an object.

for example in the directive's controller:

```
$scope.myInput = {};
```

in the html:

```
<input ng-model="myInput.value"... />
```

and than we can access the myInput in onChange event.

here is an update plunk with the solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gwfl0y?p=preview

hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Or just pass the value into the function like this

```
<input type="text" ng-change="onChange(myInput)" ng-model="myInput" />

$scope.onChange = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
};
```

Comment: 10x, but obviously it's not the typo that I'm facing. some how the values that printed in the console is undefined.
here is the typo fixed plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/EnPE7p?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Oops! typo!

```
<input type="text" og-change="onChange()" ng-model="myInput" />
```

should be

```
<input type="text" ng-change="onChange()" ng-model="myInput" />
```

EDIT: update to address OP problem indicated in comment.

The issue is that you are using a surrounding `ng-if`, which sets up an isolated scope. This means that the controller's `$scope.myInput` is not the same as the model of the input since it is a literal.

So there are two solutions, you can either remove the ng-if, or your can change myInput to an object, which will be inherited correctly.

```
$scope.myInput = {
    val: ''
};

<input type="text" ng-change="onChange()" ng-model="myInput.val" />
```

Since I expect that you want the second solution (the ng-if is important) I updated the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qNPQi9vNVxCstAHaIpLo?p=preview) with this one.
Hope this helps!

Comment: 10x @hassassin see my comment above.